Why is Numpy converting an "object"-"int" type to an "object"-"float" type?
This could be a bug, or could be something I don't understand about when numpy decides to convert the types of the objects in an "object" array.
X = np.array([5888275684537373439, 1945629710750298993],dtype=object) + [1158941147679947299,0]
Y = np.array([5888275684537373439, 1945629710750298993],dtype=object) + [11589411476799472995,0]
Z = np.array([5888275684537373439, 1945629710750298993],dtype=object) + [115894114767994729956,0]
print(type(X[0]),X[0]) # <class 'int'> 7047216832217320738
print(type(Y[0]),Y[0]) # <class 'float'> 1.7477687161336848e+19
print(type(Z[0]),Z[0]) # <class 'int'> 121782390452532103395

The arrays themselves remain "object" type (as expected). It is unexpected that the Y array's objects got converted to "floats". Why is that happening? As a consequence I immediately loose precision in my combinatorics. To make things even stranger, removing the 0 fixes things:
X = np.array([5888275684537373439, 1945629710750298993],dtype=object) + [1158941147679947299]
Y = np.array([5888275684537373439, 1945629710750298993],dtype=object) + [11589411476799472995]
Z = np.array([5888275684537373439, 1945629710750298993],dtype=object) + [115894114767994729956]
print(type(X[0]),X[0]) # <class 'int'> 7047216832217320738
print(type(Y[0]),Y[0]) # <class 'int'> 17477687161336846434
print(type(Z[0]),Z[0]) # <class 'int'> 121782390452532103395

I have tried other things, such as using larger/smaller numbers, but rarely (if ever) end up with "floats". It is something very specific about the size of these particular "int" values.

Better code that shows the problem.
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,1],dtype=object) + [2**62,0]
B = np.array([1,1],dtype=object) + [2**63,0]
C = np.array([1,1],dtype=object) + [2**64,0]
D = np.array([1,1],dtype=object) + [2**63]
E = np.array([1,1],dtype=object) + [2**63,2**63]
print(type(A[0]),A[0]) # <class 'int'> 4611686018427387905
print(type(B[0]),B[0]) # <class 'float'> 9.223372036854776e+18
print(type(C[0]),C[0]) # <class 'int'> 18446744073709551617
print(type(D[0]),D[0]) # <class 'int'> 9223372036854775809
print(type(E[0]),E[0]) # <class 'int'> 9223372036854775809


Most likely [1158941147679947299,0] is converted to int dtype array, and controls the addition. [1158941147679947299] may remain a python scalar. Math on object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss, not nearly as well defined and consistent as regular numeric arrays.

@hpaulj But regular numeric arrays can't be used if one is using ints with several hundred digits in them. EDIT: Added a better example that shows it isn't doing a conversion, since [2**63,0] fails but [2**63,2**63] works.

I am going to assume this is a bug and not a feature. I went ahead and posted it https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/26818

Can't you explicitly specify object dtype for the second list/array.  Tell it exactly what you want it to do.

@hpaulj OMG, yes!! That works AND I don't have to code change all my code into for loops. Genius. If you want to post that I will accept it.

In [323]: X = np.array([5888275684537373439, 1945629710750298993],dtype=object)

Case 1 - not too large integer in second argument:
In [324]: X+[1158941147679947299,0]
Out[324]: array([7047216832217320738, 1945629710750298993], dtype=object)

Same thing if we explicity make an object array:
In [325]: X+np.array([1158941147679947299,0],object)
Out[325]: array([7047216832217320738, 1945629710750298993], dtype=object)

2nd case - conversion to floats:
In [326]: X+[11589411476799472995,0]
Out[326]: array([1.7477687161336848e+19, 1.945629710750299e+18], dtype=object)

Again with explicit object it's ok:
In [327]: X+np.array([11589411476799472995,0],object)
Out[327]: array([17477687161336846434, 1945629710750298993], dtype=object)

Converting the list to array, without dtype spec makes a float - which propagates through the sum:
In [328]: np.array([11589411476799472995,0])
Out[328]: array([1.15894115e+19, 0.00000000e+00])

where as the first case is small enough to be int64:
In [329]: np.array([1158941147679947299,0])
Out[329]: array([1158941147679947299,                   0], dtype=int64)

third case - remaining int:
In [330]: X+[115894114767994729956,0]
Out[330]: array([121782390452532103395, 1945629710750298993], dtype=object)

In [331]: X+np.array([115894114767994729956,0],object)
Out[331]: array([121782390452532103395, 1945629710750298993], dtype=object)

This is large enough to remain object dtype:
In [332]: np.array([115894114767994729956,0])
Out[332]: array([115894114767994729956, 0], dtype=object)

So the key difference is in how the list is made into an array.  Object dtype is a fallback option, something that's used when it can't make a "regular" numeric array.    You should always assume that object dtype math is a 'step child', something that's chosen as second best.
The second case, without the 0, is another dtype:
In [334]: np.array([11589411476799472995])
Out[334]: array([11589411476799472995], dtype=uint64)

It is never wise to make assumptions about when a list is converted into an object dtype array.  It that feature is important, make it explicit!

Your answer is very helpful. However, I don't agree with your assessment that a user should know "dtype is a 'step child'". The problem is not with the user is assuming consistency with A+[2**62,0], A+[2**63,0], A+[2**64,0], A+[2**62,2**62], A+[2**63,2**63], A+[2**64,2**64], A+2**62, A+2**63, A+2**64. Rather numpy should be handling this differently. Either raise an error/warning, make all lists cast in the same way, or make all large ints cast in the same way, or make all small ints cast in the same way. Here we don't have any of that.

As long as the value fits in a int64, it's an int. But once it exceeds that, NumPy switches to float, until it exceeds twice that value, and then it switches back to int since the Python int has arbitrary precision.
import numpy as np
import sys

a = np.array([0, 0], dtype=object) + [sys.maxsize, 0]
b = np.array([0, 0], dtype=object) + [sys.maxsize + 1, 0]
c = np.array([0, 0], dtype=object) + [(2 * sys.maxsize) + 1, 0]
d = np.array([0, 0], dtype=object) + [2 * (sys.maxsize + 1), 0]

print(sys.maxsize)
for x in [a, b, c, d]:
    print(type(x[0]), ':', x[0])

Output:
9223372036854775807
<class 'int'> : 9223372036854775807
<class 'float'> : 9.223372036854776e+18
<class 'float'> : 1.8446744073709552e+19
<class 'int'> : 18446744073709551616

You could consider it a bug (or just undesirable) that numpy picks int instead of np.int64 as the type for a (and X) but there may well be a reason that this is by choice because operations on the value could cause overflows and you did specify object.
Consider:
a = np.array([0, 0], dtype=np.int64) + [sys.maxsize, 0]
b = np.array([0, 0], dtype=np.int64) + [sys.maxsize + 1, 0]
c = np.array([0, 0], dtype=np.int64) + [(2 * sys.maxsize) + 1, 0]
d = np.array([0, 0], dtype=np.int64) + [2 * (sys.maxsize + 1), 0]

for x in [a, b, c, d]:
    print(type(x[0]), ':', x[0])

Output:
<class 'numpy.int64'> : 9223372036854775807
<class 'numpy.float64'> : 9.223372036854776e+18
<class 'numpy.float64'> : 1.8446744073709552e+19
<class 'int'> : 18446744073709551616

Which may be closer to what you were expecting.
Note that the sums in your example work out to this:
7047216832217320738    # your X[0] < sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807    # sys.maxsize
17477687161336846434   # your Y[0] > sys.maxsize
18446744073709551616   # 2 * (sys.maxsize + 1)
121782390452532103395  # your Z[0] > 2 * (sys.maxsize + 1)

Also note that both the value you're adding and the sum matter:
import numpy as np
import sys

a = np.array([0, 0], dtype=np.int64) + [(2 * sys.maxsize) + 1, 0]
b = np.array([0, 0], dtype=np.int64) + [2 * (sys.maxsize + 1), 0]
c = np.array([sys.maxsize, 0], dtype=np.int64) + [(2 * sys.maxsize) + 1, 0]
d = np.array([sys.maxsize, 0], dtype=np.int64) + [2 * (sys.maxsize + 1), 0]
try:
    # compare e to c
    e = np.array([sys.maxsize + 1, 0], dtype=np.int64) + [(2 * sys.maxsize) + 1, 0]
except OverflowError as e:
    print(e)

for x in [a, b, c, d]:
    print(type(x[0]), ':', x[0])

Output:
int too big to convert
<class 'numpy.float64'> : 1.8446744073709552e+19
<class 'int'> : 18446744073709551616
<class 'numpy.float64'> : 2.7670116110564327e+19
<class 'int'> : 27670116110564327423

Adding (2 * sys.maxsize) + 1 to sys.maxsize still results in a numpy.float64, but trying to add (2 * sys.maxsize) + 1 to sys.maxsize + 1 results in an overflow.

I agree that these appear to be the thresholds. However, your explanation appears to suggest that A + [2**63,0] should have the same behavior as A + 2**63 or A + [2**63,2**63] and it does not. So it is not just that numpy has particular thresholds that are used, it is that numpy is inconsistent when those thresholds apply (if this is an expected feature).

Another note. My understanding is that dtype=object is a way to fill the numpy array with pointers instead of ints, floats, or whatever else. Those pointers can be ANY python object and that in general, numpy will defer to how that python object behaves. It is inconsistent in general for numpy to set about convertiing "object" types instead of doing whatever the objects tell it to. Hence A + 1 should behave similar to a for loop if the objects in A are python-objects. This is why an object array can hold 1000 digit integers and do modular arithmetic with them.

You're right to note different behaviour that's confusing and perhaps undesirable in some use cases. I wanted to point out the specific boundaries, and how to avoid the seemingly arbitrary behaviour. The idea of 'pointers' here is muddying the waters. If you care about the type, you should not specific object - what NumPy does there complies, even though I agree the result can be undesirable. Why NumPy chooses one or the other is likely due to internal optimisation for specific use cases, and best investigated in its source and perhaps documentation - I did not go looking for the reason.

A key point to note: passing object as the type should not be considered as "retain whatever type I gave you". If you specifically want to retain the type passed, NumPy won't let you - instead you could set the type based on some conditional yourself.

I am unsure your desire to avoid object types. The point of them is that things like np.array(['thing','other'],dtype=object) + 's' make sense and work. The reason is because numpy defers to the object's usage of +. Pandas as well as many other modules are filled with this sort of organizational behavior. In combinatorics, things like np.array([2**100,3**100],dtype=object) % 1234 should be expected to work (as they currently do, using python's arbitrary builtin ints). In fact, creating array's over int64 in size, auto casts to object type.

The bug above, would be no different than if my strings placed in a numpy array were casted to be tuples instead at some arbitrary thresholds of string length addition.

I think the "bug" is not so much a bug but an intended feature - StackOverflow is not the place to debate design decisions in third party libraries. I understand your point and encourage you to submit the issue with the maintainers. But I'd recommend making the case for the design flaw you perceive, since I don't think this is a 'bug' in that it doesn't go against the specification.

However, I think I answered the 'why' question as well as could be expected (basically the first line of my answer). That you don't agree with the reason, is not a matter I can resolve (nor would this be the place)

I appreciate your analysis and discussion. And I agree I would have never posted this if I was convinced it was a bug from the start and was looking for feedback. However, after reviewing several examples, with large ints, stings, mixed python object types, etc. It seems much more clear this is a "bug" instead of intended.
